# Find the polynomial $f(x)$ which have the following property

Tags: polynomials

Find the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+px+q$ for which $\max\{\:|p(x)|\::\:x\in[-1,1]\:\}$ is minimal.

This is the 2nd exercise from a test I gave, and I didn't know how to resolve it. Any good explanations will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You gave an exam question that you didn't know the answer to? That seems a bit unfair.

Comment: Why did you edit back to the notation where $px$ is a term in the polynomial $p(x)$?  It is an improvement to either choose a different name for the polymonial, or for the coefficients.

Comment: Because this is the problem's statement I received at the test

Comment: @MFGFlay: The exact notation that appeared on the test is irrelevant here.  A clearer presentation would be helpful.

Comment: Dear Jonas Meyer, I understand that is a bit strange but I can assure this is the exactly statement of the problem.

Comment: @MFGFlay: It is not important what notation was used on the test.  It is a mathematical problem, which could easily be presented more clearly.  "Solve the equation $a^2 -a -5=0$" is the same problem as "Solve the equation $q^2-q-5=0$".

Comment: Well, I read again the statement from my test paper, and I edit-it. The only difference was at the beginning of the phrase: Find the ... , instead of Find all ... . I can assure you that this is the statement

Comment: Aside from the poor notation, I have to agree with Adriano.

Comment: @Adriano Note, that a polynomial of the form $x^2 + px +q$ cannot be zero.

Comment: @MFGFlay: What you don't realize is that no one else cares how the problem was written on your test.

Comment: Ok then, sorry I started this topic. I was curious on how this problem could be solve, I appreciate your responses!

Comment: MFGFlay, the problem is that you edited away someone else's improvement to the problem statement because you were under the false impression that the exact original wording mattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $p(0)=q, p(1)=1+p+q$ and $p(-1)=1-p+q$.

Thus

$$p(-1)+p(1)-2p(0)=2 \,.$$

Thus

$$2= p(-1)+p(1)-2p(0) \leq 4 \max \{ p(-1), p(1), -p(0) \} \,.$$

It follows that $\max \{ p(-1), p(1), -p(0) \} \leq \frac{1}{2} (*)$

This proves that

$$\max\{\:|p(x)|\::\:x\in[-1,1]\:\} \geq \frac{1}{2} \,.$$

Moreover, we can only get equality in $(*)$ if and only if $ p(-1)=\frac{1}{2}, p(1)=\frac{1}{2}, p(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$, if and only if $q=-\frac{1}{2}, p=0$.

It is now easy to check that $f(x)=x^2-\frac{1}{2}$ satisfies

$$\max\{\:|p(x)|\::\:x\in[-1,1]\:\} = \frac{1}{2} \,.$$

This proves that

$$\max\{\:|p(x)|\::\:x\in[-1,1]\:\} \geq \frac{1}{2} \,,$$
with equality if and only if $p=0, q=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an informal argument that doesn't use calculus. Notice that $p(x)$ is congruent to $y = x^2$ (for example, simply complete the square). Now suppose that we chose our values for the coefficients $p,q$ carefully, and it resulted in producing the minimal value of $m$. Hence, we can think of the problem instead like this:

> By changing the vertex of $y=x^2$, what is the minimal value of $m$ such that for all $x\in [-1,1], -m \le p(x) \le m$?

By symmetry, there are only two cases to consider (based on the location of the vertex).

**Case 1:** Suppose the vertex is at $(1,-m)$ and that the parabola extends to the top left and passes through the point $(-1,m)$. Using vertex form, we have $p(x)=(x-1)^2-m$ and plugging in the second point yields $m=(-1-1)^2-m \iff 2m=4 \iff m = 2$.

**Case 2:** Suppose that the vertex is at $(0, -m)$ and that the parabola extends to the top left and passes through the point $(-1,m)$. Using vertex form, we have $p(x)=x^2-m$ and plugging in the second point yields $m=(-1)^2-m \iff 2m = 1 \iff m = 1/2$.

Since $m=1/2$ is smaller, we conclude that $\boxed{p(x)=x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}}$ is the desired polynomial.

Comment: + I don't think it's informal. It's something that a grade 10 student can work through. However, you might want to deal with your cases better. I believe that they should be Case 1: Vertex outside of $[-1,1]$, then the min value of $m$ is 2; Case 2: Vertex lies within $[-1,1]$, then the min value of $m$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Hahah, yeah that's what makes this informal. I don't really justify why it suffices to consider only these two cases. I figured this out by staring at the rectangle defined by $\{(x,y) \mid -1 \le x \le 1, -m \le y \le m\}$ on a piece of paper and sketching a bunch of parabolas to find the one that seemed to fit the best. Not the most rigorous proof.

Comment: This is what I did. complete the square to $(x-h)^2 + k$, so the vertex is $(h,k)$. Then, if $h \geq 1$, we get that $f(-1) - f(1) = (-1-h)^2 - (1-h)^2 = 4h \geq 4$. This implies that $\max( |f(-1)|, |f(1)| ) \geq \frac{4}{2} = 2 $. If $0\leq h \leq 1 $, then $f(-1) - f(0) = (-1-h)^2 - h^2 = 1+2h \geq 1 $. This implies that $\max( |f(-1)|, |f(0)|) \geq \frac{1}{2} $. The other 'cases' are similar. Hence we are done.

Answer (score 2):

An answer that uses more advanced mathematics (which is probably not what you want) ...

The monic polynomial of degree $n$ that has minimal sup-norm on $[-1,1]$ is $T_n(x)/2^{n-1}$, where $T_n(x)$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$. In fact, this minimum norm property can serve as the defining property of Chebyshev polynomials.

In our case, $n=2$, so the desired polynomial is $T_2(x)/2$ = $(2x^2 - 1)/2 = x^2 - \tfrac12$.

More about Chebyshev polynomials [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

- $p''>0$ implies that $\max\{p(x):x\in[-1,1]\}=\max\{p(1),p(-1)\}$,
- $p(1)=1+p+q$ and $p(-1)=1-p+q$,
- Figure out which of those two values is bigger for each $p$ and $q$.

EDIT: I misread the question, so that the first point is wrong but can be fixed looking at $p(v_x)$ where $v_x$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex $v_x=\frac{-p}{2}$.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the absolute value.

Comment: ops! I made an edit to point out where the error was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, but I must sleep now.

Maxima can occur at $-1$, $1$, and points where the polynomial has derivative $0$.

At $-1$, the polynomial has absolute value $|1 - p + q|$.

At $1$, it has absolute value $|1 + p + q|$.

$p'(x) = 2x + p$, which vanishes at $x = -p/2$ (assuming this is in range), at which point the absolute value is $|p ^ 2/4 - p^2/2 + q|$ = $|-p^2/4+q|$